# iOS - Cannot Push View Controller with TabbarController Showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, show-hide

My storyboard is as below:

[image]

```
UINavigationController 
    |
 UITabbarController
      |
    HomeVC - Container
                 |
               PageViewController
                    |
                  MainVC | MenVC | WomenVC | ElectronicsVC ...
```

I try to push a new view controller from MainVC, using tabbarcontroller. I want the bottom tabbar to be visible but I can't. Everytime when new viewcontroller is pushed, it will be in full screen.

In my NavigationHelper.m,

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainV3" bundle:nil];
    MyNewViewController *myNewVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNewViewController"];
    [myTabbarController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO];
    [myTabbarController.navigationController pushViewController:myNewVC animated:YES];

    // I have checked myTabbarController and myNewVC instances are not nil.
```

The reason why I use pageviewcontroller in this design because I need few view controllers in first item of tabbarcontroller.

Set tabbarcontroller **setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed** property to YES before I push new controller is not working too.

I have checked the container inside HomeVC is not covering the tabbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you invoke `push` on `myTabbarController.navigationController`, you actually add one more controller on the same hierarchy level as your `UITabBarController` controller.

```
UINavigationController 
      |
  UITabBarController  –> YourPushedViewController
```

Which obviously hides entire `UITabBarController` along with its bar and everything it contains.

If you want to have navigation inside particular **tab** — you should place `UINavigationController` inside this tab, and then do `push` using it.

So your new hierarchy should be something like this.

```
UITabBarController
    |
   FirstTab — SecondTab — ...
    |
   UINavigationController
    |
   HomeVC - Container
              |
           PageViewController
                |
              MainVC | MenVC | WomenVC | ElectronicsVC ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the black magic. It works. So yea my storyboard follows what you suggested. I will study further on UINavigationController. However I push it by using pageviewcontroller because it's part of the item inside the container of MainVC.

Comment: could you please provide working sample code for the same @wcf

Answer (score 2):

you need to set your TabBarController as root of the app, like in this scheme:

```
TabBarController -> Tab1 -> UINavigationController -> ViewContoller1 -> ViewContoller2.
```

ant not like:

```
NavigationController -> TabBarController -> VC1 -> VC2
```

In such case you can navigate between ViewContoller1 and ViewContoller2 and TabBarContoller will remain visible.